# intent to send data to another activity doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a problem with transferring data from one activity to another! I have read everything I can. I did not find a solution to my question anywhere. I do everything as described in official sources, but I do not transfer values. I will be grateful for any help. Thank you.
This is how I send

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Osnova.class);
    intent.putExtra("url122", url122.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is how I try to get

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_osnova);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("url122"); 
}
```

As a result, it only outputs null.As a result, it only outputs null.utl122 if that is already a string value. I also tried to send an object by adding .getText().toString(); but still nothing works

Comment: `url122.toString()` We do not know what that would be. If it is null you got what you put. Put a hard coded string value in it first to test like: intent.putExtra("url122", "we wanne see what this does");

Comment: I tried that too. It still gives null